# Distributing chrome extension from registry

Tags: windows, google-chrome-extension, registry

I want to check if it's possible to distribute some chrome extention via registry, [acording to this link](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/external_extensions#registry) it is possible

[image]

I tried it on some random chrom extension [like this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/honey/bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj), I followed the steps, but still I can't see the extension in my `chrome://extensions`

what I'm doning wrong?

Here want I tried (Windows 64 bit):

[image]

Comment: Just tried it and it works for me. Open `chrome://policy` and see if there's something relevant. Also make a [log file](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) and see if it contains something relevant. P.S. make sure you've exited Chrome by clicking `Exit` in the browser menu so it closes all hidden processes.

Comment: Do note that this will install the extension, disable it immediately, and ask the user whether they want it enabled. This flow is intended for browser add-on components of external software, e.g. antivirus software or Skype click-to-call.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you!, after I clicked `Exit` and re-opened chrome it downloaded the extension